# Proyecto laravel en CPANEL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cpanel

Tengo un problema al desplegar mi proyecto en CPANEL ya que la página de inicio de mi proyecto es: http://192.163.229.242/~prueba

En mi servidor (CPANEL) tengo alojado todo de manera correcta.

Las primeras rutas me funcionan por ejemplo:

http://192.163.229.242/~prueba/login la cual al ingresar al sistema me manda a http://192.163.229.242/~prueba/home aquí es donde comienza el problema pues mi menú pierde la ruta y si hago clic en alguna opción que me mande a otra ruta quita esta parte: /~prueba/ y me pone otra ruta, por ejemplo http://192.163.229.242/registrarUsuario la cual no existe, para poder acceder a esa ruta tengo que agregar /~prueba/ entre la ip y la ruta para que funcione, por ejmplo: http://192.163.229.242/~prueba/registrarUsuario  espero me puedan ayudar ya que no logro encontrar el error, no se si sea alguna modificacion en mi .env o en el htaccess.

Gracias

Comment: No creo que la quite... debe de existir algún error en tu código. Podrias editar la pregunta y mostrar el código de tu menú?

Comment: que version de PHP tenes? version de laravel?
que significa "tengo alojado todo de manera correcta"?

Comment: En efecto, tenía un error ya que no usaba URL para indicar las rutas; en local funcionaba pero al momento de subirlo al servidor no las identificaba. Gracias